# Postgres - unable to clear all rows & then rewrite/replace scrapy pipeline data

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, web-scraping, scrapy

Using scrapy to collect data & then saving it to postgres. I have one table named auto_records I wish to completely replace each time data is scraped. Seems like it should not be too difficult but I'm having some weird behavior.

```
class AutoRecordsPipeline(object):

def open_spider(self, spider):
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = 'xxxxxxx'
    database = 'autos'
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
    self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
    self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM auto_records") #MOVED HERE AS PER COMMENTS

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.cur.close()
    self.connection.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        #self.cur.execute("VACUUM FULL auto_records")
        #self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM auto_records")
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO auto_records(make,year,color,miles) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['make'],item['year'],item['color'],item['miles']))
    except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
        self.conn.rollback()
    else:
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

Initially I tried `VACUUM FULL` (commented out above) but I got the error `psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block` so then tried the current delete statement. What I see now when I print the table to the console like so

```
autorecs = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM "auto_records"', con=engine)
print('from autos db auto_records',autorecs)
```

is just the last record that gets scraped

```
from autos db auto_records    id                    make         year color miles
0  30  Chevrolet  2019    blue     30157
```

I don't understand where the `0 30` comes from, seems like it should be `0 1` or `29 30` since there's a total of 30 records. If I comment out the delete statement I get too many records b/c of the `INSERT INTO` statement. Don't know if it has to do with the scrapy pipeline or something else but I'm hoping someone has an idea as to what the real issue is... thanks

Comment: Are you intending to delete all of the data in the table and then insert one record in process_item?

Comment: Agreed w/ @Jeremy. Instead try putting the command to delete the records in the `open_spider()` method, so that it's just run at the beginning; and not each time through in `process_item()`. Right now, you're just deleting *everything* from the table, and then inserting only one record.

Comment: Thanks @mechanical_meat as per your comment now it's working